# No parser could be inferred for file (while creating project in generator-easu-ui5)

Tags: sapui5

I was trying to create project with generator-easy-ui5, but I am facing the following issue I have tried many node versions but still end up with same issue

[image]

I have tried with many node versions but still end up with same issue.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Install NodeJS version 18
2. Execute `npm install -g yo generator-easy-ui5`
3. Execute `yo easy-ui5` project